# Opto Isolator 150 V Square Wave Output

Tags: opto-isolator, high-voltage, output

I am trying to design a circuit that enables me to use low voltages to control an actuator that works with high voltage. I think I need to use an opto-isolator.

[image: First, I want to get the ~150 V square output but I get this.]

How can I get a 150V square wave output from with an opto isolator?

I appreciate any type of help or comment.

Thank you.

Comment: Step 1: find an optoisolator that can withstand 150 V across the output when non-conducting.

Comment: Step 2: define which node in your circuit is the output node.

Comment: Google "High voltage optocoupler", and you might find [**this**](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/4N/4N38M.pdf)

Comment: Thank you so much @ThePhoton. The output is going to be from the emitter. I have already googled the optocouplers that I need to use and found the ones that you have provided. My concern is actually the basics. I am planning to use 100 kHz pulses with PWM. Would I be getting the same frequency at the output?

Comment: Which opto did you choose?

Comment: Your schematic shows the inputs and outputs grounded, so if you don't need isolation, why don't you just use a high voltage bipolar transistor or MOSFET  to drive your load?  Also, it would help a great deal if you'd explain in detail what it is you want to do, post the actuator's data sheet (or a link to it), and describe the nature and source of your PWM signal.

Comment: Thank you so much @EMFields, I think H11D1M or 3M will the one that I need.

Comment: I have a piezo actuator. I need to control its charging and discharging. I tried to use a high voltage nmos but since my control voltage is low, the transistor worked in the saturation region. I could not reach to 150 volt at the source. Then, I thought that maybe I could use an opto-isolator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

V2 -> Charge signal.
V3 -> Discharge signal.

[image]

The blue one is the Vg of M1. 
The red one is the Vg of M2.
The green one is the voltage of the capacitor (basically a piezo actuator).

Comment: A fairly complicated setup but it certainly does the job.

Comment: Thanks @winny, I used this but I am not sure if that creates a problem on the actuator. I think I would not know before I test it.

Comment: Should be fine.

Comment: Is there any way that I get almost a square pulse at the output of the opto-isolator?

Comment: Remove L1 and replace C1 with a resistor.